# Create a new Hotspot with just Terminal and NetworkManager/nmcli

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi-hotspot

i have a Raspberry Pi 1 Model B with Raspbian / Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7+ installed.

I have two USB Adapter:

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
>
> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]

So the first Interface wlan0 should be able to access other WIFI AP regularly.
This is not a problem. It works.
But Interface wlan1 should start as an AP itself with the SSID: paketBox
No password required.

I tried different approaches but nothing worked so far.
On my Laptop i can just click "Use as Hotspot" and then I can edit the Config Files (Fedora 22). Very easy and it works.

I tried to create a new Connection with nmcli following this:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/CLI

my Hotspot config file at `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`
looks like this:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=03620827-416a-49a2-ab1f-e7987c079cbe
interface-name=wlan1
type=wifi

[wifi]
ssid=paketBox
mac-address=74:da:38:5b:5c:2d
mode=ap

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=shared
```

i restarted NetworkManager and then i tried:
`sudo nmcli con up Hotspot ifname wlan1`
the result was this:
`Error: Connection activation failed: Connection 'Hotspot' is not available on the device wlan1 at this time.`

So my question is the following: what am i missing?
Does NetworkManager has other config files?
I mean i would expect to just create a correct file at the correct position and to restart the NetworkManager. And it should just work.

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e0:eb:8f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6608 (6.4 KiB)  TX bytes:6608 (6.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:54:79:bc  
          inet addr:192.168.178.72  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:894 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:144069 (140.6 KiB)  TX bytes:80780 (78.8 KiB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:da:38:5b:5c:2d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

edit:
also did a `sudo nmcli con reload` (got no error) followed by a
`sudo nmcli dev disconnect wlan1`
(`Error: Device 'wlan1' (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3) disconnecting failed: This device is not active` )
followed by:
`sudo nmcli con up wlan1` (`Error: neither a valid connection nor device given.`)
and again, just to be sure: `sudo nmcli con up Hotspot ifname wlan1`
(`Error: Connection activation failed: Connection 'Hotspot' is not available on the device wlan1 at this time.`)

edit2: output of syslog after reinstalling raspian and setting up
networkmanager. this time i tried also the adhoc mode.
error: `Error: Connection activation failed.`
here is the link to the snippet:
[syslog snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/11353/raw)

Comment: I think I have a very similar problem on my RasPi 2 with the same WiFi Dongle. Maybe NetworkManager has the same problem with this chipset as hostapd (see e.g. http://www.daveconroy.com/turn-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-edimax-nano-usb-ew-7811un-rtl8188cus-chipset/ or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=103825&p=717560 ), but I can't find a solution for NetworkManager.

Comment: well until now i did not find any solution with networkmanager/nmcli. then i thought i should just go with hostapd for my wlan1 interface and let it be in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. wlan0 is managed by network manager. i followed this howto: `http://jankarres.de/2015/06/raspberry-pi-wlan-access-point-einrichten/`  it is in german. but i think it is very clear.

Comment: Sure that's a possible workaround, but I'd really like to use NetworkManager, it's just so much easier... And I don't understand why it works with Ubuntu 15.04 on my notebook, but not with the newer Raspbian Jessie. Maybe I'll try to install some different OS on the RasPi, if I have time.

Comment: well with hostapd it is not that hard. if you want i can send you some config files of mine. and a little script to "toggle" the service. but i understand you. i wanted the solution with network manager so it is just one package i need to run the system. but it is ok now with hostapd+networkmanager.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm quite sure I could do it with hostapd if I wanted too (the tutorial you linked above looks good, and I am german). I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703715/enable-monitoring-mode-for-rtl8188cus-via-usb-on-raspbian and I will try that now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description in the [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703715/enable-monitoring-mode-for-rtl8188cus-via-usb-on-raspbian) that I linked in my comment above actually worked on my RasPi 2 with Raspbian Jessie. I simply followed steps 0-4 there (changing step 3 as needed for the RasPi 2 hardware according to [the official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md)) and then set up the access point with network manager.

I took all the settings for the latter from the access point I created with ubuntu on my notebook. In particular,

```
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         rsn
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      ccmp
802-11-wireless-security.group:         ccmp
```

seem to be somehow important for WPA.

However, the downside might be that you probably have to do all the compiling again every time a new kernel version is released.

Comment: i won't try this solution (since really no time and the project is actually finished).  but if you say it worked for you i guess i should accept this answer for now